# What is the easiest way of adding a button to the last column of this table being appended to?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

This snippet from my code uses a function to take the data from my indexedDB Database and append it to a table.

The next thing I need to do is to add a button to delete a task from the list and database which I want to do by having a button at the end of each row of tasks which can select the task by ID and remove it from the database which should be reflected by the table.

```
 const db = new Database();

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      db.getAllTodos(function(records) {
          records.forEach(function() {
            console.log(records.length)
            var cols = ['taskName','taskDesc', 'taskDate','taskTime','taskPriority','taskLocation','taskImage']
              for (var i = 0; i <= records.length; i++){
                $('table').append('<tr></tr>' );
                for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {
                  $('table tr:last-child').append ('<td>' + records[i][cols[j]] + '</td>' ); 
                }
              }
            })
      });
    }, 1000);
});
```

Below are some images of my web page and database for reference:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zx8CN.jpg

I was thinking of doing this by adding the button as data into the database but it always appeared as null or undefined when I tried to put it in.

Answer (score 0):

**Hi SourOddity,**

Perhaps adding the button HTML tag just before the last TD or even better in a separated TD inside the same TR would be the trick for this case. You can then use the button ID to invoke the click event on it in order to run your delete function. I certainly hope this helps!

```
$('table tr:last-child').append ('<td>' + records[i][cols[j]] + '</td>' + "</td><button id='delbtn' type='button'>Delete</button></td>");
```

I have made some edits to the code, and now it looks like this:

```
const db = new Database();

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      db.getAllTodos(function(records) {
          records.forEach(function() {
            console.log(records.length);
            var cols = ['taskName','taskDesc', 'taskDate','taskTime','taskPriority','taskLocation','taskImage'];
              for (var i = 0; i <= records.length; i++){
                $('table').append('<tr></tr>' );
                for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {
                  var lastCell = $('table tr:last-child');
                  lastCell.append ('<td>' + records[i][cols[j]] + '</td>' );
                }
                lastCell.append("<td class=\"delete\"><button onclick=\"deleteTask()\">Delete</button></td>");
              }
            })
      });
    }, 1000);
});

function deleteTask() {
  console.log("working");
}
```

This solution works to add the buttons, however I now get
[this error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cW6Kr.png)

The lines of code mentioned but not visible from database.js

```
async getAllTodos(callback) {
        let store = this.database.transaction(["taskList"], "readonly").objectStore("taskList");
        let allRecords = store.getAll();
 
        allRecords.onsuccess = () => callback(allRecords.result);
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked if the record property taskName it comes like that on the array? Also, I am not sure if the record is still in the process of being populated before attempting to print this data, I mean I would first make sure with a conditional if the length of record is greater than 0, meaning it has some data. Perhaps at the moment of running the script this array is still empty or not even created(see undefined) and for that reason the taskName property cannot be found.

Comment: Im not sure really, going through step by step it seems fine, its like the loop is trying to continue after populating the data or something.

Comment: yeah, that is weird, probably some of that is causing the delay on the array's data delivery but I am unable to reach that much with your code, but at least we tried the part of the buttons and that is now working, I am glad that I was able to help up at least with something. Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

Answer for adding button is above, gonna close this one as question is moving off topic.